# ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I run Jenkins, sonarqube each docker and I install sonar-scanner in sonarqube docker. And I check sonarqube in my browser localhost:9000 works
I configure sonarqube and github repo in jenkins, and I build project in jenkins I got error MSG

```
Started by user user
Building in workspace /bitnami/jenkins/workspace/refrigerator-manager
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/dean- 
kim/refrigerator-manager # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/dean- 
kim/refrigerator-manager
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/dean- 
kim/refrigerator-manager +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # 
timeout=10
Checking out Revision 619639b2a173a3aa58ec05c13442168f7a8e49dd 
(refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 619639b2a173a3aa58ec05c13442168f7a8e49dd
Commit message: "fix sonar-project.properties file"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 619639b2a173a3aa58ec05c13442168f7a8e49dd # 
timeout=10
[refrigerator-manager] $ /sonar-scanner-3.1.0.1141-linux/bin/sonar- 
scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 ******** - 
Dsonar.projectName=Refrigerator-manager -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 - 
Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=my:project - 
Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 - 
Dsonar.sources=refrigeratior_manager - 
Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/bitnami/jenkins/workspace/refrigerator-manager
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /sonar-scanner-3.1.0.1141- 
linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: 
/bitnami/jenkins/workspace/refrigerator-manager/sonar- 
project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.9.41-moby amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/tomcat/.sonar/cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------
INFO: Total time: 0.441s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/59M
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
ERROR: Caused by: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
ERROR: Caused by: Connection refused (Connection refused)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full 
debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the 
SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

And here is my sonar-project.properties in my github repository project root directory.

```
sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=Refrigerator-manager
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=refrigeratior_manager

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
```

Here is my jenkins system configuration for sonarqube

[image]

Here is my jenkins global tool configurations for sonarqube scanner

[image]

Here is my Jenkins project configuration for execute sonarqube scanner

[image]

I searched google for solve this problem few days but I can't find solution.

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue, and get sonarqube scanner running on port 9000?

Comment: Possibly you might need to add "http://" to the url in your properties file. That was the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your sonarqube scanner running when you run you build from Jenkins ??
If not, it will throw the above message because jenkins is trying to listen to the port 9000 but nothing is there.

Comment: thx, I run sonar-scanner in sonarqube docker it does not work, I will check sonar-scanner

Answer (score 0):

I have the question like as you

> Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?

I try use `-X` in the Additional arguments.It can see enable full 
debug logging.You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you use proxies, Sonar will use the first one from your maven `.m2/settings.xml`, so if you have several entries, only the first one will be tried.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
        <!-- europe proxies (main proxy first for sonar!) -->
        <proxy>
            <id>http-eu-proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>web-proxy.eu.mycompany.com</host>
            <port>8080</port>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>https-eu-proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <host>web-proxy.eu.mycompany.com</host>
            <port>8080</port>
        </proxy>

        <!-- india proxies -->
        <proxy>
            <id>http-in-proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>web-proxy.in.mycompany.com</host>
            <port>8080</port>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>https-in-proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <host>web-proxy.in.mycompany.com</host>
            <port>8080</port>
        </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

my /sonar.sh is started but still i'm not able to open local host